# 'Weighted' Markov Chain Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, descriptive-statistics

Let $\mathbf{X} = (X_0, X_1, ..., X_n)$ be a finite length walk on a Markov chain with initial distribution $\lambda$, transition matrix $P$, over the state space $\Omega = \{1, 2, ..., l\}$.

Suppose that we also associate weights, $w_1, w_2, ..., w_l$ with each state in the state space.

I am interested in calculating certain statistics arising from this set up.

For example, let $W$ denote the *total weight* of the walk (that is, the sum of the weights associated with each successive state that the walk lands on).

> **How can we calculate $\mathrm{Var}(W)$?**
>
> **What can be said about the distribution of W?**

Any insight, including approximations, (e.g. using CLT for distribution of $\overline{W}$) or any heuristic inference methods, would be much appreciated.

If it helps, **the transition probabilities are expected to be small**.

---

**Additional info:**

Let $W_k$ denote the weight associated with the $k$-th state, $X_k$,
so that $W = W_0 + W_1 + \cdots W_n$.

Let $\mathbf{w} = \begin{bmatrix} w_1 & w_2 & \cdots & w_l \end{bmatrix}^T$.

It is relatively straightforward obtain the formulae,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(W) & = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbb{E}(W_k) \\
& = \lambda \left( \sum_{k=0}^n P^k \right) \mathbf{w}
\end{align}
$$
and similarly,
$$
\mathbb{E}({W_k}^2) = \lambda P^k \mathbf{w}^{\circ 2}
$$
(where $\circ 2$ denotes the [Hadamard power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Analogous_operations)).

However, where I seem to be getting stuck is calculating $\mathbb{E}(W_k W_{k+r})$ (without getting a long winded formula which is essentially just the definition of expectation!). An expression for this should lead to an expression for $\mathrm{Var}(W)$...

Comment: To calculate $E[W_kW_{k+r}$], write it as $E[W_k(W_k+W_{k+r}-W_k)]=E[W_k^2]+E[W_k(W_{k+r}-W_k)]$.  The first term you already know. For the second term, $E[W_k(W_{k+r}-W_k)]=E[W_kE[(W_{k+r}-W_k)|W_k]]$, so use the Markov property on the inner parenthetical term.

Comment: @AlexR. I see what you're getting at, but I think that you may have mistaken $W_k$ for the partial sum of weights up to the $k$-th step (correct me if I'm mistaken!)... I will use your idea of conditioning on $W_k$ though. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I've got the same question, and taking it down to the same place: $E[W_kW_{k+r}]$. I don't quite see what @Alex R. is doing.